# Symfony2: error trying to send an email with Swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I have the following issue when I try to send an email with swift in a 
Symfony2 project : Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ".

I am in localhost and I try to use a mail of my host OVH. Here is my config.yml:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    auth_mode: "%mailer_auth_mode%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    port:      "%mailer_port%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

And my parameters.yml:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: ********
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: mail
    mailer_auth_mode: login
    mailer_host:  ns0.ovh.net
    mailer_port: 587
    mailer_user: contact@******.com
    mailer_password: **********
    locale: fr
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What version of SwiftMailer did you install? The mail transport is deprecated from SwiftMailer 5.4.5.

> Starting from SwiftMailer 5.4.5, the mail transport is deprecated and will be removed in version 6. Consider using another transport like smtp, sendmail or gmail.

You can see more info at this links:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#transport

http://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html

You need to change the `mailer_transport`. Try with this config, editing the port, encryption, host...

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: smtp.example.com
    mailer_user: user@example.com
    mailer_password: my_password
    mailer_port: 587
    mailer_encryption: tls
```